# Quick Graph Example IN VB.NET Forms Application

Tags: vb.net, quickgraph

I'm Looking for Example of using [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) in VB.Net I have searched but i cannot find complete code and also they were in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better  to use Graph Sharp And Graph X